# difference btween different between and difference between

Tags: grammar, difference

Should I use "What is different between…" or "What is the difference between…"? I already searched about it, but it doesn't help me.

Comment: [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What+is+different+between%2CWhat+is+the+difference+between&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWhat%20is%20different%20between%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWhat%20is%20the%20difference%20between%3B%2Cc0) is your friend here

Answer (score 1):

"How" is the right word to use with "different". I.e. "How are apples different from oranges?" Which brings up the always dicey question of whether it's correct to use "from" or "than"... but that's for another post. Using "how" opens the question up. There could be zero differences or several thousand.

"What is the difference between apples and oranges?" would also be correct, grammatically, but it implies that there's only one difference between the two things being compared. You could open that up by using "differences".